# How to set proxy for xerces-c for VC++?

Tags: xerces-c, codesynthesis

Using CodeSynthesis XSD 3.3 I've generated code to read and write XML.

When trying to read, however, I get connection problems (probably because I'm behind a proxy):

```
:0:0 error: unable to connect socket for URL 'http://www.uncertml.org/uncertml.xsd'
```

I've seen possible solutions on UNIX/Linux using libcurl, but how can I do this in VC++?

Alternatively, how can I stop xerces-c from wanting to access the internet? (I have all the schemas downloaded)

Answer (score 0):

"Solved" it by turning off the validation of the XML:

```
ifstream ifs("test.xml", ifstream::in);
auto_ptr<Test>  = Test_(ifs, xml_schema::flags::dont_validate);
```